# Python Telegram Bot‘s webhook goes into infinite loop

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, python-telegram-bot

I built a simple telegram bot that runs on Google Cloud Functions. My webhook looks like this:

```
def webhook(request):
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=os.environ["TELEGRAM_TOKEN"])
    if request.method == "POST":
        update = telegram.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force=True), bot)
        #my code calls functions in here
    return "ok"
```

The problem at this point is that my code takes too long to run, which causes either Telegram or Google Cloud (haven’t quite figured that out yet) to resend the request, creating more instances, sending more requests …

My only idea at this point would be to send the „ok“ answer before my code runs, which doesn‘t seem right to me (and I don‘t know how to do tbh). So please point me in the right direction on how to deal with these situations.

Comment: Your question contains insufficient data for us to provide much help. Please include details of the incoming `request` (obfuscate confidential properties); the command you're using the deploy the Cloud Function, the configuration you're providing to register it as a webhook, add logging statements to your function and include logs from Cloud Logging. Have you tried invoking the Cloud Function using e.g. curl? If so, please include the sample request and response.

Comment: I‘ve looked through the official documentation of Telegrams API and found this part that confirms my thoughts so far: „Whenever there is an update for the bot, we will send an HTTPS POST request to the specified url, containing a JSON-serialized Update. In case of an unsuccessful request, we will give up after a reasonable amount of attempts. Returns True on success.“ https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook  So I guess I just need to figure out how to send an „ok“ answer before running my code.